# Delete 'Up-sells' link from Magento Backend- Catalog - Manage Products - Product Information - Up-sells

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, catalog, up-sells, delete

Magento 1.9.0.1, After numerous attempts to remove this link via files in the Mangento file system I'm at a total loss as how to proceed. I have attempted to comment out lines of code in .php files, .xml files, removed rows from the DB based on tutorials online, altered/deleted functions and outright tried every possible variation of these steps. This is the culmination of 2 months hard work and I'm stuck! I simply don't want 'Up-sells' in my product information as a link when I'm setting up a product. The link that I don't want is pictured below. Please help, any suggestions will be greatfully received.

[image: I don't Up-sells link showing at all, as a link or page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab is added in the Adminhtml module, more exactly in this file: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php`

To remove it, you just have to remove the following piece of code:

```
    $this->addTab('upsell', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Up-sells'),
        'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/upsell', array('_current' => true)),
        'class'     => 'ajax',
    ));
```

As you may probably know, you should never modify core files. Instead, copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php` and edit this new file, which will overwrite the one in the core directory.

P.S. This is not the most recommended solution either (but the quickest). The best way would be to create a custom module

Comment: Hi Alex, that's awesome and totally helped me out, I also removed cross-sells and related products. I tried to 'up-vote' this answer however this was my first interaction and I don't have permissions Yet. Very much appreciated and maybe I can answer your question one day. Many thanks, John

Comment: Glad I could help :) even if you cannot upvote, you can at least accept the answer. Cheers